# Is there a way to detect zoom in Matplotlib plots and set minor tick format according to zoom level?

Tags: python, matplotlib, zooming, axis-labels

I want to plot a large data range but have ability to zoom in and gain resolution.  I need to use custom major and minor tick formatting therefore I lose the ability to have them set dynamically with the zoom level.  Is there a practical solution to this problem?

Comment: You just need to create your own [`tick formatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#tick-formatting) and then set it as the formatter for the x axis (major and or minor).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to create your own `tick formatter` and then attach it to the `axes` object.

[This](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/date_index_formatter.html) example has everything you need. Essentially, create a function which takes the value of the tick, and returns what you would like the tick label to be - call it `my_formatter`, and then do this:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(my_formatter))
```

and optionally

```
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(my_formatter))
```

Where the [`ticker.FuncFormatter(my_function)`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter) creates the custom formatter for you.

Comment: This answer does not answer on setting the minor tick based on zoom level

Answer (score 4):

If the formatting of the ticks actually depends on the zoom level, one needs to define a tick formatter that has access to the axis limits. Unfortunately, this cannot directly be done using [ticker.FuncFormatter](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html?highlight=ticker#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter) since the function passed to the constructor does not take the axis limits as a parameter.
A way of getting access to the axis limits is by inheriting from [ticker.Formatter](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.Formatter) and overriding the `__call__` method.

As an example, such a class could be defined as follows.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import Formatter

# Custom formatter class
class CustomFormatter(Formatter):
    def __init__(self, ax: Any):
        super().__init__()
        self.set_axis(ax)

    def __call__(self, x, pos=None):
        # Find the axis range
        vmin, vmax = self.axis.get_view_interval()
        # Use the range to define the custom string
        return f"[{vmin:.1f}, {vmax:.1f}]: {x:.1f}"
```

Afterwards it can be used in the following way.

```
formatter = CustomFormatter(ax)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```

In this way, the range will be adjusted accordingly if you zoom. Similarly, this can be achieved for the minor ticks.

Full example for testing and playing around:

```
data = [1, 4, 2, 7, 4, 6]
ax = plt.gca()
ax.plot(data)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(CustomFormatter(ax))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: **Warning:** The above works flawlessly for me with `v3.2.1` but with `v3.3.4` I get an error saying that *three arguments were passed when two were expected*. I think the underlying `Ticker` function signatures have changed between the versions. Couldn't look into this further. Reverted to the old version due to deadlines.

Comment: @pfabri I could not reproduce your error, tested it using version 3.3.4 on Python 3.7.9 and 3.8.6 on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

The other answers talk about `Formatter`s. But the formatter is simply how it displays, to vary the number of tick levels you need a `Locator`. So if you also wish to vary the number of ticks per the zoom level, add a custom Locator.

The easiest way is to subclass `MultipleLocator` and change its limits depending on the current view range.

Here's an example from a plot that has an xaxis of 0-43,200 representing the number of seconds (so, 12 hours worth). It has a formatter to display the ticks in terms of hours/minutes, but it's this Locator that adds the minor ticks depending on zoom level. It displays no minor ticks at full zoom, but as you get closer it shows the half hour marks, then every 5 mins, then every 1 min.

```py
class ZoomLevelMultipleLocator(matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator):

    def __init__(self, offset) -> None:
        super().__init__(base=30 * 60, offset=offset)

    def tick_values(self, vmin: float, vmax: float) -> Sequence[float]:

        if vmax < vmin:
            vmin, vmax = vmax, vmin
        vrange = vmax - vmin

        num_hours = vrange / 3600
        if num_hours > 4:
            return []

        if num_hours <= 0.25:
            minutes = 1
        elif num_hours <= 1:
            minutes = 5
        elif num_hours < 2:
            minutes = 15
        else:
            minutes = 30

        super().set_params(base=minutes * 60)
        return super().tick_values(vmin, vmax)
        
def configure_xaxis(ax, stats):
    # Major ticks
    def format_hours(x, pos):
        t = x - stats.test_start_time
        hours = int(t // 3600)
        return f"{hours}h"

    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(format_hours))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator(
        base=3600,
        offset=stats.test_start_time
    ))

    # Minor ticks
    def format_minor(x, pos):
        t = x - stats.test_start_time
        hours = int(t // 3600)
        minutes = int((t % 3600) / 60)
        seconds = int(t % 60)
        return f"{hours}h{minutes}m"

    ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(format_minor)
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ZoomLevelMultipleLocator(offset=stats.test_start_time))

    ax.set_xlim(xmin=stats.test_start_time, xmax=stats.test_end_time)
    ax.xaxis.set_label_text('Time (seconds)')

    ax.tick_params(which='both', width=2)
    ax.tick_params(which='major', length=7)
    ax.tick_params(which='minor', length=4, color='r')
```

If you combine this with the accepted answer of a CustomFormatter than you can also change how the axis are labelled as you zoom in too.