# Python plot showing minor ticks automatically when zooming

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series, ipython, spyder

I was trying to use plot to show time series over a long period of time. Since it is a long time series, I used **major ticks over every 14 Days** and **minor over every 7 Days**.

**I do not need it to show smaller ticks including hours, min and seconds, as ticks will overlapping, making it mess.**

But the problem is, when **zooming in**, the figure does not shows smaller ticks.

For example, in the figure below, when it is zoomed in, I want to see the **smaller ticks**:

> 1/1 2/1 3/1...15/1

, and further smaller ticks on hours:minutes:seconds scale

> 1/1 12:00:00 1/1 12:05:00....

*How should the following code be revised?*

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols, figsize=figsize)
xticks = pd.date_range(data.index[0], data.index[-1], freq='14D')
xticks_minor = pd.date_range(data.index[0], data.index[-1], freq='7D')
xtickslabel = xticks.strftime('%d/%m')

for i, ax in enumerate(ax.flat):
    ax.plot(data, '.',color='k',zorder=2)
    ax.set_xlim(data.index[0],data.index[-1])
    ax.set_xlabel('t ('+str(data.index[0].year)+')',fontsize = 14, family='Arial')
    ax.set_ylabel(varstr[i], fontsize = 14, family='Arial')
    ax.set_xticks(xticks)
    ax.set_xticks(xticks_minor, minor=True)
    ax.set_xticklabels(xtickslabel, rotation=0, fontsize=14)
#    ax.set_yticklabels(rotation=0, fontsize=12)
    myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m') # formate date of x-axes to make x calues shown on the figure %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
    ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=14) # y-axes label size
    labels = ax.get_xticklabels()+ax.get_yticklabels()
    [label.set_fontname('Arial') for label in labels] 
    ax.grid(which='major',alpha=0.5,linestyle=':')
    ax.grid(which='minor',alpha=0.5,linestyle=':')
```

The resulting figure is as follows:
[image: figure not automatically showing minor ticks]

Comment: Then don’t set the ticks and use the automatic tick locator?

Comment: @Jody Klymak Yes, it can show smaller ticks. but the ticks will be like 1/1 00:00:00... which looks mess

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of having an increased number of minor ticks as you zoom in. This example is from a plot that has an xaxis of 0-43,200 representing the number of seconds (so, 12 hours worth). It has a formatter to display the ticks in terms of hours/minutes, but it's this Locator that changes the number of minor ticks depending on zoom level. It displays no minor ticks at full zoom, but as you get closer it shows the half hour marks, then every 5 mins, then every 1 min.

If you wish to also change how those ticks are labelled, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65628075/57461) about custom formatting with zoom level.

```py
class ZoomLevelMultipleLocator(matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator):

    def __init__(self, offset) -> None:
        super().__init__(base=30 * 60, offset=offset)

    def tick_values(self, vmin: float, vmax: float) -> Sequence[float]:

        if vmax < vmin:
            vmin, vmax = vmax, vmin
        vrange = vmax - vmin

        num_hours = vrange / 3600
        if num_hours > 4:
            return []

        if num_hours <= 0.25:
            minutes = 1
        elif num_hours <= 1:
            minutes = 5
        elif num_hours < 2:
            minutes = 15
        else:
            minutes = 30

        super().set_params(base=minutes * 60)
        return super().tick_values(vmin, vmax)


def configure_xaxis(ax, stats):
    # Major ticks
    def format_hours(x, pos):
        t = x - stats.test_start_time
        hours = int(t // 3600)
        return f"{hours}h"

    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(format_hours))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator(
        base=3600,
        offset=stats.test_start_time
    ))

    # Minor ticks
    def format_minor(x, pos):
        t = x - stats.test_start_time
        hours = int(t // 3600)
        minutes = int((t % 3600) / 60)
        seconds = int(t % 60)
        return f"{hours}h{minutes}m"

    ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(format_minor)
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ZoomLevelMultipleLocator(offset=stats.test_start_time))

    ax.set_xlim(xmin=stats.test_start_time, xmax=stats.test_end_time)
    ax.xaxis.set_label_text('Time (seconds)')

    ax.tick_params(which='both', width=2)
    ax.tick_params(which='major', length=7)
    ax.tick_params(which='minor', length=4, color='r')
```

Note: This answers the question title, rather than the specific question of

> How should the following code be revised?